# How to make my post featured in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a create post function and I would like to make a certain section only have a featured post. I'm new to laravel and php so was not to sure how to do it. I created a featured column in my db and passed a foreach($posts as $featured) into the section I wanted featured. From my research, the idea I saw was to toggle between a default value of "0" and a featured value of "1". Not sure where to go from there

EDIT: using the ->default(0) and re-running the migration did the trick. Now the question is how I can toggle between 0 and 1

Route:

```
// Store Listing Data
Route::post('/posts', [PostsController::class, 'store']);
```

Posts Controller (Create function):

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $formFields = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'sub_title' => 'nullable',
        'tags' => 'required',
        'content' => 'required',
        'featured' => 'nullable',
    ]);

    Posts::create($formFields);

    return redirect('/'); 
}
```

Posts Model

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'sub_title', 'tags', 'content','featured'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on a right way! Your column must be `tinyint` and it will accept values of `1` and `0`. `1` means the post is featured and `0` means its a normal post. Your migration must look like this

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    // ...
    $table->tinyInteger('featured')->default(0);
    // ...
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now when you insert a post it will be automatically inserted as a `normal post`. If you want the post to be inserted as featured you must declare it while inserting the post like this:

```
Post::create([
   'title' => 'My first post',
   'sub_title' => 'I am so glad I published this post',
   'tags' => 'first_post , so_glad',
   'content' => 'My first post contents',
   'featured' => 1 // THIS MEANS THE POST WILL BE FEATURED
]);
```

And then whenever you want to retrieve all featured posts you can do

```
Post::where('featured', 1)->get();
```

That's it! Now you listed all the featured posts!

Comment: Thanks for the response, ok so I added the column to my table and migrated it. So instead of 'nullable', I should change it to just 1? Then in my create form, I have passed the attribute name="featured" to my checkbox. So this will automatically toggle between 0 and 1?

Comment: Nullable, in the simplest form of explanation, means that the column can be empty (no value). You don't need to put additional input in your HTML Form. When a new post is inserted it will be with (specified default) value `0` of the column `featured` which means it will be a normal post. If you specify the value while inserting `'featured' => 1` - it will be a featured post.